# C# Random number unique first number

Tags: c#

If I create a Random() with a different starting seed every time will the first number in the generator be unique every time, or is there a point in which the first number will start repeating?

Example:

```
var random1 = new Random(1);
var value1 = random1.Next();
var random2 = new Random(2);
var value2 = random2.Next();
var random3 = new Random(x);
var value3 = random3.Next();
```

where value1 != value2 != value3;

EDIT: Fixed variable names
I have tested seeds of 0-80,000,000, I am just wondering if they are unique from 0-int.Max, or if the first 80,000,000 are unique by accident

Comment: They could all be exactly the same, thats the point about random

Comment: The first number will be random every time hence the name.

Comment: Random.Next generates a random number whose value ranges from 0 to less than Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: Why don't you run this code yourself and see what actually happens?

Comment: In only six lines, your use of single-alpha variable names manages to completely obfuscate intent. **Meaningful variable names, people.** Especially when crafting an example meant not for execution, but to be read by humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I don't think there is any requirement that pseudorandom generators should generate unique numbers given unique seeds.

The only think it happens is that, given a seed, the generator will always generate the same number sequence (obtained by calling multiple times the next method) and the sequence will repeat at some point. 
However, the C# Random class uses a subtractive generation algorithm, where the next random number is generated basing on previous numbers of the sequence. Hence, there may be some kind of dependency between the number and the seed, which makes the random number generator to generate unique numbers every time the seed is changed.

If you want to be sure, either try it yourself with seeds from `int.MinValue` to `int.MaxValue`, or check the `C#` implementation here
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs